# Shell.SearchHandler puts large amounts of blank space in search results

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Im trying to make simple app and I would like to use search in the toolbar, xamarin has `SearchHander` for `Shell` apps which seems perfect for me. I was able to implement it but the results returned in the search list have a lot of blank space around the items. I tried looking for examples and following them to the letter, also the example xaminals from Microsoft documentation but nothing helps.

[screenshot from app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmbwE.jpg)

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:App1.controls"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <Shell.SearchHandler>
        <controls:TitleBarSearchHandler ShowsResults="True" >
            <controls:TitleBarSearchHandler.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Nazev}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Typ}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:TitleBarSearchHandler.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:TitleBarSearchHandler>
    </Shell.SearchHandler>
```

Comment: Can yo utry with a StackLayout intead of Grid?

Comment: nope, it makes the blank space even if i just use DisplayMemberName, so i think the problem is somewhere outside the datatemplate

Comment: @NathanielHiggers Hi, do you have a try with adding the `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` for `Grid` to check whether it works?

Comment: i tried that, doesnot work. I eventually set up new project and copied all the classes and pages to that new project where it works ok, still got no idea what went wrong the first time tho ...

Comment: @NathanielHiggers Okey, because I can not reproduce it in my project, if you have time, you could share an sample project link here to check.